# In yq, how can I get multiple nodes by key names and return the key names with their content?

Tags: yq

I have the following data.

```
_format_version: "1.1"
_info:
  select_tags:
    - test
_workspace: test
plugins:
  - blah: abc
routes: 
  - blah: def
services: 
  - blah: ghi
```

I need to extract the keys that start with underscore and return the keys with their content.
Example:

```
_format_version: "1.1"
_info:
  select_tags:
    - test
_workspace: test
```

All attempts fail to return the keys with the content.

```
$ yq '._format_version,._info,._workspace' test.yml
1.1
select_tags:
  - test
test
```

I have tried `in()`, `select()` and `match()` but can't get any of them to work.

```
$ yq eval 'select(keys[] | in(["_format_version", "_info", "_workspace"]))' test.yml 
Error: 1:17: invalid input text "in([\"_format_ver..."
```

I tried `del()` to delete all non-matching keys but I cannot get `| not` to work. Using `not` still deleted _info.

```
$ yq 'del(._info | not)' test.yml
_format_version: "1.1"
_workspace: test
plugins:
  - blah: abc
routes:
  - blah: def
services:
  - blah: ghi
```

I am running yq on Mac OSX.

```
$ yq --version
yq (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version v4.35.2
```

Answer (score 1):

With `._*`, you can access all keys that start with an underscore. Get each `key`, collect them into an array `[…]`, and use the `pick` [function](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/pick#pick-keys-from-map) to filter your input map by them.

```bash
yq 'pick([._* | key])' file.yaml
```

```yaml
_format_version: "1.1"
_info:
  select_tags:
    - test
_workspace: test
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  It's simple and it works great!